# How can I make this SQL query work again

Tags: sql, firebird

This query used to work fine but the trainers table no longer contains a name field so obviously it doesn't work anymore. The trainers table does contain the person_id and the trainer is a person in the persons table. With some other mechanism (nested select, self join, ...) I need to get the person_id from the trainer table, and then get the trainers name from the persons table, and then return the information in the same format as the original query.  Can this be done with one statement?

```
SELECT 
    entries.entry_id, entries.entry_no, dogs.name, 
    persons.name, trainers.name 
FROM 
    entries 
JOIN 
    dogs ON entries.dog_id = dogs.dog_id
JOIN 
    persons ON dogs.owner = persons.person_id
JOIN 
    trainers ON entries.trainer_id = trainers.trainer_id
WHERE 
    entries.show_id = 5
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Firebird, I figured it didn't much matter for this question, pretty standard SQL isn't it?

Comment: @user1455270 Every database has its quirks, it is better to be explicit, even if the answer turns out to be standard SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just do an extra join with persons. Also: get into the habit of using aliases for every table you join. It increases readibility and you have to type less.

```
SELECT e.entry_id, e.entry_no, d.name, p.name, tp.name
  FROM entries e
  JOIN dogs d ON e.dog_id = d.dog_id
  JOIN persons p ON d.owner = p.person_id
  JOIN trainers t ON e.trainer_id = t.trainer_id
  JOIN persons tp ON tp.person_id = t.person_id
  WHERE e.show_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove trainers.name from the select field list
2. add JOIN person tname    ON person.id = trainers.trainer_id
3. add tname.name to select field-list

that should do it (if I read your text correctly)